# Trying to access mockedFunction.mock.instaces property gives undefined in Jest

Tags: jestjs, jest-fetch-mock

I want to mock a constructor function named Dog

```
Dog = jest.fn(()=>{
    return{
        name:"spike",
        bark:function(){
            return "bhow " +this.name;
        }
    }
})

function foo(){
   const d = new Dog();
   return d.bark();
}




test("testing foo",()=>{
    const result = foo();
    expect(Dog).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(result).toBe("bhow spike");

    expect(Dog.mock.instances.length).toBe(1);

    expect(Dog.mock.instances[0].name).toBe("spike");
    //this test failed with expected spike received undefined
});
```

but the `expect(Dog.mock.instances[0].name).toBe("spike");`
fails with expected spike received undefined

jest version 24.8.0
node version 10.15.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a function with the `new` operator, a new object is created and passed as the execution context (aka `this`) to the function. This object is then implicitly returned if the function does not return anything explicitly. You can have a look at the [detailed explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

Also, take into account that an [arrow function can never be used as a constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Use_of_the_new_operator).

From Jest documentation for [mock functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockinstances):

> **mockFn.mock.instances**
>
> An array that contains all the object instances that have been instantiated from this mock function using new.

So, Jest mock functions are storing in the `instances` attribute the list of object instances that are being passed to the function (the newly created object that is passed as `this` to the function) every time you call it with the `new` operator.

But your constructor is not using the `this` object, so it remains empty. That is why when you check `Dog.mock.instances[0].name` you are getting `undefined`. If you change slightly your constructor to assign the *name* attribute to the `this` object you can see that your test passes:

```
Dog = jest.fn(function() {
    this.name = "spike";
    return{
        name:"spike",
        bark:function(){
            return "bhow " +this.name;
        }
    }
})
```

Returning explicitly an object from a constructor function as you are doing is rarely used. The most usual way to define a constructor is to assign its properties to the `this` object. So, a solution to your problem would be to change your constructor function to:

```
Dog = jest.fn(function() {
    this.name = "spike";
    this.bark = function(){
        return "bhow " +this.name;
    }
})
```

Another solution, if you don't want to change the definition of your constructor function, would be to use the `results` [attribute](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockresults) of the mock function in your test:

```
test("testing foo",()=>{
    const result = foo();
    expect(Dog).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(result).toBe("bhow spike");

    expect(Dog.mock.instances.length).toBe(1);

    expect(Dog.mock.results[0].value.name).toBe("spike");
});
```

Comment: almost...just change the arrow function to a normal function.  An arrow function can never be a constructor function because it has no `this` of its own (it always uses the `this` of the scope where it is defined)

Comment: You are absolutely right. I edited the answer to correct that. Thanks!